# UrlRewrite Not working for GAE/J

Tags: google-app-engine, url-rewriting

Not sure what am i doing wrong, I am using http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/#

1) put the jar file in lib directory
2) update web.xml with following code

```
    <filter>
         <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
         <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>  
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
         <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

3) copied urlrewrite.xml into the WEB-INF directory and added following rule

```
    <rule enabled="true">
           <from>^/view/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)$</from>
           <to>/view?id=$1&amp;title=$2</to>
</rule>


    <outbound-rule>
           <from>^/view?id=([a-z]+)&amp;title=([a-z]+)$</from>
           <to>/view/$1/$2</to>
    </outbound-rule>
```

4) Also updated my JSP page with following - (/view -> is servlet which redirects to view.jsp?id=123&title=my%20title)

```
<a href="<%= response.encodeURL("/view?id="+id+"&amp;title="+title)%>">
```

my expectation was -- to generate URL inside HTML as well as browser window as follows ...

www.mywebsite.com/view/123/my-title

5) but really - my URL is becoming ->

so not sure what am i doing wrong so my URL is not getting rewritten friendly way.